# How can I remove list style in Outlook?

Tags: html, css, outlook, email-templates

I have an unordered list, which is rendering fine on all email clients except for outlook on windows. On windows outlook it renders with the bullet point despite me setting `list-style-type: none`

```
  <ul class="mob-list-style"
    style="text-align: left; padding-left:110px; list-style-type: none;"> 
         <li>&#8208; Order online</li>
         <li>&#8208; Order Delivery</li>
         <li>&#8208; In Store Collection</li>

  </ul>
```

I hav tried adding Outlook conditional statement in order to remove the bullet point (see below), but that still doesn't work. Any ideas how I can stop the bullet points showing in windows outlook?

```
   <!--[if gte mso 9]>
        <style>
    li {
        text-indent: 50px;
        list-style-type: none;

        }
    </style>
    <![endif]-->
```

Answer (score 1):

Give this a try. Your style for `list-style:none` should be at the list item as those show the bullets/numbers (on ordered list).

```
<ul class="mob-list-style" style="text-align: left; padding-left:110px;"> 
    <li style="list-style:none;">&#8208; Order online</li>
    <li>&#8208; Order Delivery</li>
    <li>&#8208; In Store Collection</li>
</ul>
```

Let me know if this works.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't appear possible to remove them, however, you can conditionally push them off to the side so it appears removed.

Put this in your `<head>` section:

```
  <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
  <style type="text/css">
    li {
        text-indent: -3em;
    }
  </style>
  <![endif]-->
```

If you need this only for that list, add the class, i.e. `.mob-list-style li { ...`